# formatting the long sql string which contains double quotes

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a winform app which is connected to access database as data-source , as i can't use stored procedures unlike in Mysql , i am in desperate try of executing the query and populate the same in data-grid view box.(earlier i wan using the same excel in my access database query)
But again i am struck how to enter this long sql with correct formatting , please help me how to encapsulate this sql string in my code .

```
private void FormMainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cSCDataSet.master_table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.master_tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.cSCDataSet.master_table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Read();
        }

        private readonly OleDbConnectionStringBuilder _builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            DataSource = "S:\\Customer_Service\\Wires\\Database for CSC\\Backend data of databse do not open\\CSC.accdb"
        };

        public DataTable Read()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            using (var cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = _builder.ConnectionString })
            {

                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand { Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"TRANSFORM Count(Complaint_Number) AS [Total Numbers]
                                       SELECT Nature_of_problem, Count(Complaint_Number) AS[Total Numbers of Issues]
                                       FROM master_table
                                       GROUP BY Nature_of_problem
                                       PIVOT Format(Complaint_Received_On, "mmm") In("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"); 
                    cn.Open();
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }

            return dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you give us a SQL statement that doesn't do what you want, and you ask us to give the a SQL statement that DOES do what you want. Wouldn't it be easier for us if you'd edit the question and add your requirement: what is your SQL expected to do? What are the relevant parts of your table?

Comment: No i have the sql that work(and you can see the same in the code) , just i don't know to how to format it to include double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your problem has nothing to do with Winforms.

> just i don't know to how to format it to include double quotes

In SQL string quotes are with single quotes, like [this example from SQL IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

So if you need this command text in a c# string:

```
const string sqlCommandText = @"
    SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')";

cmd.CommandText = sqlCommandText;
```

Answer (score 1):

You double double quote .`""`

[Working Solution](https://rextester.com/NZMYY81321)

Comment: Could you also upvote if you do not oppose please ? @RAVIKUMAR